# How to loop through files in a request without knowing their name in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a REST API which needs to have a generic file uploader for temp files. The problem is that these files can come from multiple parts of the UI and all those parts have different name properties for the file input which is responsible for sending the file.

For example:

```
<input type="file" name={"image"} /> // Somewhere in the UI in a form
<input type="file" name="video" /> // somewhere else in the UI in a different form, or possibly a different UI even
```

Here for instance, I have 2 input fields which need to send their files to the same route but have a different name. Assume that the name can vary and there is no way to write some kind of switch/case or if/else logic to determine all the names which occur in the UI as there are multiple UIs built by different people. I need to make this as universal as possible.

How do I get the file from the `request.files` dictonary if I do not know the name of the input field which is used to identify the file in the request? I have tried to print the file but i get an empty dict.

I have tried to do a `for in` loop through the `request.files` dict like so:

```
files = request.files
print(files["image"]
for f in files:
    print(f)
```

but that didn't work. I just got an empty dict again despite confirming that the file is in the request with the print on line 2.

The content type is `multipart form-data`. Here is how I generate the form data:

```
const data = new FormData()
data.append(e.target.name, e.target.files[0])
```

but that can vary depending on the UI.

tl;dr: I need to be able to retrieve any file from the `request.files` dictionary without knowing the name with which the file was uploaded.

Comment: from UI you can ask for metadata, like what kind of file is it, or in headers you can find what kind of file it is.  or save see the extension of file then save accordingly

Comment: You say that `print(f)` returns an empty dict, right? That's strange as it should return `image` i.e. the name of the file. Can you add the output of both `print` statements?

Comment: Yes. I also had an enumerate in my for loop, and i incorrectly named the for loop arguments (i thought the array member would be first, followed by the counter but its the other way around apparently). So i was trying to get request.files[1], request.files[2] instead of request.files[file1name], request.files[file2name].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the piece of code to see the corresponding input names given in HTML file.

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/",methods=['GET','POST'])
def home():
    if request.method == "POST":
        for i in request.files:
            print(i)
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And here is the Template file (index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test App</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <form action="/" method="POST" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        <input name="unnamedfile1" type="file">
        <input name="unknownfile2" type="file">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the output after submitting the form :
[image]